# Very Strange PHP File Upload error

Tags: php, html, forms

I have a form that allows the user to upload a file, along with some other data. This is then passed to a PHP file which attempts to upload the file, and then write some of the passed data as well as the file location to a JSON index. However, over half the images I attempt to upload will simply print

> "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file."

which is my catch-all error. The strange part is that some images will display every error code simultaneously, including a PHP error

> "Undefined index: img_upload".

Some checking with echo statements showed that in these cases it appears that the image data isn't even being passed to the PHP function. However, when these errors occur the upload ends up succeeding.

PHP:

```
<?php

#Image code
$target_dir = "../BlogPosts/post_images/";
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["img_upload"]["name"]);
$uploadOk = 1;
$imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
// Check if image file is a actual image or fake image
if (isset($_POST["submit"])) {
    $check = getimagesize($_FILES["img_upload"]["tmp_name"]);
    if ($check !== false) {
        echo "File is an image - " . $check["mime"] . ".";
        $uploadOk = 1;
    } else {
        echo "File is not an image.";
        $uploadOk = 0;
    }
}
// Check if file already exists
if (file_exists($target_file)) {
    echo "Sorry, file already exists.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
// // Check file size
//if ($_FILES["img_upload"]["size"] > 500000) {
//    echo "Sorry, your file is too large.";
//    $uploadOk = 0;
//}
// Allow certain file formats
if ($imageFileType != "jpg" && $imageFileType != "png" && $imageFileType != "jpeg" && $imageFileType != "gif") {
    echo "Sorry, only JPG, JPEG, PNG & GIF files are allowed.";
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
// Check if $uploadOk is set to 0 by an error
if ($uploadOk == 0) {
    echo "Sorry, your file was not uploaded.";
// if everything is ok, try to upload file
} else {
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["img_upload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
        echo "The file " . basename($_FILES["img_upload"]["name"]) . " has been uploaded.";


#All other code
        $postbody = $_POST["newpost_body"];
        $posttitle = $_POST["newpost_title"];
#Preparing the post summary
        $postsummary = substr($postbody, 0, 175);
        $postsummary = $postsummary . "...";
        $postsummary = strip_tags($postsummary);
        $postsummary = preg_replace("/&quot;/", "\"", $postsummary);
        $postsummary = preg_replace("/&#39;/", "'", $postsummary);


#Uploading post text
        $filepath = dirname(__FILE__) . "/../BlogPosts/";
        $fileid = time();
        $filename = $filepath . $fileid . ".html";
        $var_str = var_export($postbody, true);
        $var = "$postbody";
        file_put_contents($filename, $var);
        $posts = json_decode(file_get_contents(dirname(__FILE__) . "/../BlogPosts/posts.json"), true);
#$posts->append($fileid);
        $filedata = [
            "ID" => $fileid,
            "Title" => $posttitle,
            "Date" => gmdate("m.d.y", $fileid),
            "Summary" => $postsummary,
            "Thumb" => $target_file,
        ];

        array_push($posts['posts'], $filedata);

        $arr1 = $posts;
        file_put_contents(dirname(__FILE__) . "/../BlogPosts/posts.json", json_encode($arr1));
# array.json => {"a":1,"b":2,"c":3,"d":4,"e":5}


        header('Location: #/blog');
    } else {
        echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
    }
}
```

HTML Form:

```
<form id="bpost_form" class="dropzone" method="post" action="/admin/writetofile.php" style="text-align:center" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <input type="text" name="newpost_title"/>
            <br>
            <input type="file" name="img_upload" id="fileToUpload">
            <br>
            <textarea name="newpost_body" id="newpost" rows="10" cols="80">
                This is my textarea to be replaced with CKEditor.
            </textarea>
            <script>
                // Replace the <textarea id="editor1"> with a CKEditor
                // instance, using default configuration.
                CKEDITOR.replace('newpost');
            </script>
            <input type="submit"
                   value="Save"/>
        </form>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In cases like this, I personally would break down the script into different tasks, in this case, two. One to upload, second to deal with what you are referring to as `#All other code`. For this example I am choosing to do the upload via a class with it's own contained errors. It will return `true` or `false` based on success of the upload which the other code will execute based on that response. It will record errors along the way for reporting, as well. This may or may not be helpful. It's basically what you have, just reorganized:

**class.UploadFileEngine.php**

```
class   UploadFileEngine
    {
        public  $errors;
        public  $fileName;

        private $target_dir;
        private $fileArray;
        private $fileTypes;
        private $target_file;

        public  function __construct($filetypes = array("jpg","jpeg","gif","png"))
            {
                // Assign accepted file types here
                $this->fileTypes    =   $filetypes;
                // Set the default input name from your form
                $this->setInput();
                // Set the errors array by default
                $this->errors       =   array();
            }

        public  function setDestination($target_dir = false, $make = true)
            {
                // Assign the destination
                $this->target_dir   =   $target_dir;
                // If the target has been left empty, don't do anything
                if(empty($this->target_dir))
                    return $this;
                // If the folder does not exist, try and make it
                if(!is_dir($this->target_dir) && $make)
                    mkdir($this->target_dir,0755,true);
                // Return this object for method-chaining purposes
                return $this;
            }

        public  function setInput($inputName = 'img_upload')
            {
                // Assign the input name (you can change this dynamically)
                $this->inputName    =   $inputName;
                $this->fileArray    =   (!empty($_FILES[$this->inputName]))? $_FILES[$this->inputName] : array();

                return $this;
            }

        public  function uploadFile()
            {
                // If there is no upload, just return false
                if(empty($this->fileArray))
                    return false;
                // Set up the file
                // This is all pretty much the same as yours...
                $this->fileName     =   basename($this->fileArray["name"]);
                $this->target_file  =   $this->target_dir.$this->fileName;
                $check              =   (!empty($this->fileArray["tmp_name"]))? getimagesize($this->fileArray["tmp_name"]) : false;
                $ext                =   pathinfo($this->target_file, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

                if($check !== false) {
                        if(!file_exists($this->target_file)) {
                                if(in_array($ext, $this->fileTypes))
                                    return move_uploaded_file($this->fileArray["tmp_name"], $this->target_file);
                                else
                                    $this->errors[] =   'File extention invalid. Must be '.implode(", ",$this->fileTypes);
                            }
                        else
                            $this->errors[] =   'File already exists';
                    }
                else
                    $this->errors[] =   "File is not an image";

                return false;
            }

        public function getTargetFile()
            {
                return (!empty($this->target_file))? $this->target_file : false;
            }
    }
```

**To use:**

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST["submit"])) {
        include_once("class.UploadFileEngine.php");
        $destination    =   "../BlogPosts/post_images/";
        $uploader       =   new UploadFileEngine();
        $success        =   $uploader   ->setDestination($destination)
                                        ->uploadFile();

        $targetFile     = $uploader->getTargetFile();
        if($success) {
                // do rest of code here
            }
        else
            echo implode('<br />',$uploader->errors);
    }
```

Comment: Okay, so I have some questions. Hope they aren't too dumb, I find PHP's syntax generally confusing.

Why is setDestination initialized with $target_dir = false?

Is $this just being used as a temp variable? Or is it the equivalent of self in Python?

I really want to understand what is happening here, not just copy-paste.

Comment: This the error I got when I ran your code as is:
`Warning: getimagesize(): Filename cannot be empty in C:\Users\Adrian Smith\Google Drive\Documents\Projects\Personal Site\www\admin\class.UploadFileEngine.php on line 57
File is not an image`

If I enter an image which I know uploads correctly, `if (isset($_POST["submit"])) {` validates to false, but the image appears in  my file structure.

Comment: It's false because you don't name your submit button `<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Save"/>`

Comment: Also, on a side note, I have tested this code on my system as is and it ran A-OK. Try `print_r($this->fileArray);` right before this line: `$this->fileName =   basename($this->fileArray["name"]);`

Comment: Now that I think about it, I may have had errors turned off. Just do `$check          =   (!empty($this->fileArray["tmp_name"]))? getimagesize($this->fileArray["tmp_name"]) : false;` That should account for an empty `tmp_name`

Comment: Also, I need witertofile.php to have access to $target_file, but just doing `public $target_file` in the engine and `"Thumb" => $uploader->target_file` in writetofile.php doesn't seem to work.

Comment: After making your suggested changes, I get this error: `Array ( [name] => 2014-05-02 14.36.34.jpg [type] => [tmp_name] => [error] => 1 [size] => 0 ) File is not an image`

Comment: I pulled up the metadata for an images that works, and an image which throws the above error. They were taken with the same camera, and are the same filetype. The notable differences are size (1.44mb vs 2.29mb), and the Attributes value (A vs. N). Attributes is just some Microsoft indexing thing, so it shouldn't matter. Seems like it is the size which determines whether an upload succeeds, but that doesn't seem to match the error.

Comment: I am not in front of my computer how but when I am I will review these comments.

Comment: Try upping the `max_upload_size`, see if that will work better

Comment: That fixed the issue, thanks! However, I need witertofile.php to have access to $target_file, but just doing `public $target_file` in the engine and `"Thumb" => $uploader->target_file` in writetofile.php doesn't seem to work. Sorry to keep having to ask you all this stuff, I've been messing with PHP for a while and it still doesn't come naturally to me.

Comment: Alright I revised it. See if it will retrieve as I have written it.

Comment: All fixed, thank you so much. Sorry for making you practically rewrite my code from scratch. Hopefully next time I can figure it out on my own.

Comment: No problem, the key is to break your tasks down by function or by class, you will make your script more portable and faster to use. Cheers!

Comment: I forgot to answer your very first question, which was what's the deal with the `$target_dir = false` as a parameter. I do that because if nothing is entered into the function, then the default value is `false` otherwise it will draw an error saying it's undefined or what-have-you, so I just assign it a value like false then deal validation inside the function/method. I just don't like drawing an error when the function runs improperly. The `setDestination()` method, should probably have a check if `empty` or not. I will revise.

Comment: As for your other question, "what is `$this` doing?" `$this` is in reference to itself as an object. It's primary allowing for "method chaining" on the object. It allows you to do this `$new = new Object(); echo $new->medthodOne()->methodTwo();` otherwise if it did not return itself, you would achieve the same thing by: `$new = new Object(); $new->methodOne();  echo $new->methodTwo();` I usually do it if the first method in the chain is processing a variable or array that the second method is going to use in an altered stated. In terms of a "pattern" it would best be described as a "Factory."

Comment: Okay, so would it be reasonable to think of it as basically equivalent to self.var in Python on this.var in JavaScript?

Comment: Well, `$this->var` would be equivalent of `this.var`. (Bare with me, I am not a js expert) but in jQuery I think it would be the equivalent of `Object1.methodOne().methodTwo();` If you don't return `$this` you would only be able to return the current method without the ability to tack on anymore, so `Object1.methodOne();` would be as far as you could go.

Answer (score 0):

Also note that if you are using dropzone.js, you will need to set the file name that dropzone uses. In your html form you have `<input type="file" name="img_upload" id="fileToUpload">` and then in your php script you use `$_FILES["img_upload"]`.

However, by default dropzone will name the file "file" instead of "img_upload".
You can change what dropzone will use with "paramName:", see http://www.dropzonejs.com/#configuration. Or just change your form and php to "file".

Comment: I decided against using dropzone in the end.